# PHP upload image through AJAX issue

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I want to upload the image to a /uploads/ directory in my root file but here's the problem: my AJAX does not get a response from the server, and I don't think I'm accessing the image's data for upload. Please take a look at my code:

HTML form:

```
<form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method = 'post' id="dashboard_create_BPost_form" onsubmit="return false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Javascript (jQuery ajax)

```
$("#dashboard_submit_new_BPost").on('click', function(){
     var property = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var image_name = property.name;
    var image_extension = image_name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    if(jQuery.inArray(image_extension, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1){
        alert("Invalid Image File");
    }

    var image_size = property.size;
    if(image_size > 6000000){
        alert("File size exeds 6 MB");
    }else{
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("file", property);
        $.ajax({
            url: './includes/functions.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{
                publishBlogPost : 1,
                data : form_data,
            },
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: (res)=>{
                console.log(res)
            },
            error: (jqxhr, status, exception)=> {
                alert('Exception:', exception);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is my back-end in functions.php

```
if(isset($_POST['publishBlogPost'])){

        if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != ''){
            $test = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($test);
            $name = rand(100, 999). '.' .$extension;
            $location = './uploads/'.$name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
            
        }
        echo '123';
}
```

Note that I am not receiving 123 in console in the success method within the AJAX call.
Thank you in advance

Comment: should it be `new FormData(this)`? [see an example at external page](https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-jquery-php-mysql/)

Comment: welll, probably easier for you to look in your apache, php fpm logs than posting here.  `["tmp_name"]` ???

Comment: You are sending the request to `./includes/functions.php` rather than the current page - is that correct?

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_FILES)` to see the received data.

Comment: Start with `var_dump($_FILES);` or use inspector tools of your browser to verify what data are passed in your POST payload.

Comment: You might wish to try processing `php://input` in your `functions.php` script - ie: `file_get_contents('php://input')` - you are sending `data` in the ajax function rather than the `$_FILES['file']`

Comment: Nothing works, replies comes back empty always. My pay load just says 'object' due to the fact that im using FormData() to send the image data to the server.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Could you kindly provide me with an edited code? I'm not sure I understand what you're insinuating.

Comment: Ignore the comment regarding `php://input` - there are times when you need to process that but in this case the problem was the way you were sending the FormData itself. See answer below...

Answer (score 0):

The following POSTS to the same page for demonstration purposes - the PHP at the top emulates whatever code you have in `/includes/functions.php` to process the upload.

Rather than appending the `FormData` object to another `Object Literal` as the POST payload in the ajax function, send the `FormData` object as the entire payload but `append`  whatever other fields you wish to process in PHP.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $debug=false;
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $publishBlogPost=isset( $_POST['publishBlogPost'] );

        
        if( isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ){
            $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $name=$obj->name;
            $size=$obj->size;
            
            /* process upload ... */
            exit( $name );
        }
        exit( false );
    }
    
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                $('#dashboard_submit_new_BPost').on('click', function(e){
                    
                    var oFiles=document.getElementById('file').files;
                    var property=oFiles[0];
                    
                    if( !property ){
                        alert('No file selected');
                        return false;
                    }
                    var image_name = property.name;
                    var image_extension = image_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                    
                    if( jQuery.inArray( image_extension, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'] ) == -1 ){
                        alert('Invalid Image File');
                    }

                    var image_size = property.size;
                    if( image_size > 6000000 ){
                        alert('File size exeds 6 MB');
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        var form_data = new FormData();
                            form_data.append('file', property );
                            form_data.append('publishBlogPost',1);
                            
                        $.ajax({
                            url:location.href,
                            method:'POST',
                            data:form_data,
                            contentType:false,
                            cache: false,
                            processData: false,
                            
                            success:( res )=>{
                                console.log( res );
                                alert( 'ok' )
                            },
                            error: (jqxhr, status, exception)=> {
                                alert('Exception:', exception);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
            <input type='button' id='dashboard_submit_new_BPost' value='Submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```